# Google Analytics: Count users who had more than X unique pageviews

Tags: google-analytics

I have an event fire when a user has opened his 6th page.

When I segment by user with the condition 'Unique Pageviews per user > 5', then the number of users it returns is much bigger (3-5 times bigger) than the number of events that fires on the sixth pageview in the same time period.

Either there is a serious problem with this event, or the segment is not at all measuring what I thought it measures. So far it seems like the event is working as it should.

What, exactly, does the 'Unique Pageviews per User > 5' segment measure?

Is it possible by default to measure the number of unique visitors that have visited more than X unique pages in a certain time period?

Answer (score 2):

Unique pageviews per user will transcend sessions as opposed to your event which is per session.
So if a user has two sessions and each one went to 3 unique pages they would fit in with your segment.
Not only that but even if they went to the same 3 pages each time they are defined as unique based upon the session not user

Comment: The event I have works with cookies, and should work cross-session. The fact that unique pageviews are measured per session and not per user may be related to this issue though.

Comment: Even if you are firing it cross session Google is not collecting it cross session, they group all hit level interactions in buckets of sessions which are defined by the ga cookie

Comment: A cookie tracks total page visits. Once the total is more than 5, I fire an event. I set another cookie to indicate the event has fired (so I won't fire it again).

I'd expect that this event fires once for each user that has visited more than 5 pages.

But the number of these events was very different from the number Analytics came up with with the segment with condition 'Unique Pageviews per User > 5'.

(Note: The segment above was done on a property exclusively tracking blog articles, not the homepage or archive, so it's unlikely that a user visits the same page in multiple sessions).